# CSS: Adjacent sibling inside a class

Tags: css, parent-child, descendant

Trying to add a top-margin to an adjacent sibling.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Header 1</h2>
  <p>Some text and sentences...</p>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Some more text and sentences..</p>
</div>
```

Normally I would accomplish top-margin on "Header 2" by using css on the adjacent siblings.

```
p + h2{
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

However, h2 has margin defined via

```
.container h2{
  margin: 24px 0px;
}
```

How can I make the adjacent siblings css work while overriding the .container h2 css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container h2` is more specific than `p + h2` so it is taken into consideration. You need a more specific selector to override the margin.

This should be "more specific" and override:

```
.container p + h2 {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
.container > p + h2{
  margin: 12px;
}
```

That is:

- Select `h2` elements...
- ...which immediately follow a `p` element...
- ...which is a child of an element with class `container`.

Since `.container > p + h2` contains 1 class and 2 elements, it will override `.container h2`, which only has 1 class and 1 element.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
.container p + h2 {
margin-top: 12px;
}
```